# Partial sum of $p$-series

Tags: power-series, divergent-series

I need to find the following sum for $p>1$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty m^{-p}$$
 My intuition says it is supposed to converge but I cannot find a proof for this.
The formula can also be expressed as a:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty( \zeta(p) -\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} m^{-p})$$
where $\zeta(p)$ is the Riemann zeta function (which is a positive constant for any $p>1$ as far as I know). So if you can help with evaluation of $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1} m^{-p}$ this can also be very helpful.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers!
Another question is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=\left\lfloor n^{1/k}\right\rfloor }^\infty m^{-p}$$ for some $k$.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the series:-
$$1^{-p}+2^{-p}+3^{-p}+4^{-p}...$$
$$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space+2^{-p}+3^{-p}+4^{-p}...$$
$$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space+3^{-p}+4^{-p}...$$

The number $m$ occurs $m$ times. Hence Series simplifies to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot n^{-p}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1-p}=\zeta(p-1)$$
This converges for $p>2$ and diverges for $p\le 2$

Comment: Thanks alot! This is a simple explanation! 

The actual problem is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=\left\lfloor n^{1/k}\right\rfloor }^\infty m^{-p}$$ for some k. What would be the result in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $p>1$, $\sum_{m=1}^\infty m^{-p}$ is convergent.
Moreover
$$0<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty m^{-p}\leq \sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_{x=n-1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}dx=\frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)^{p-1}}$$
which converges for $p>2$.
What happens for $1<p\leq 2$? We have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty m^{-p}\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{x=n}^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}dx=\frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}=+\infty.$$